# new line in url causing bad request - invalid url when using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I have the following php:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://domain/blah/".rawurlencode("foo bar"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r ($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

That works as it should, but when I change `foo bar` to `foo\r\nbar` or `foo\nbar` or drop the `rawurlencode` and just send `foo%0D%0Abar` or `foo%0Abar`, I get a `Bad Request - Invalid URL` error.

If I try:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://domain/blah/foo\r\nbar");
```

I get no error, but nothing happens.

I can put some other characters in the url and have them replaced with newlines, but that seems a bit of a workaround.  I'm looking for the right way to do this.

I'm using php 5.6.7

Comment: Why do you have line breaks in your URL?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do exactly; I'm not sure what the question is ...

Comment: When submitting data of non trivial complexity the approach is to post them, not to use get request parameters.

Comment: You get bad request from server. You can check this copy you url in curl and past to address line your browser and load page. `bad request ` 504 http code. This error not curl this error requested server. sorry for my English

Comment: My question is - how do I send line breaks - the comments suggest I shouldn't do this via the url - that's good enough for me - I'll post them instead - thank you all